# Why do I get this warning Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given in?

Tags: php

I am new to php and I am following the book 'PHP for absolute beginners' by Jason Lengstorf and it walks you through on how to make a basic blog website.

the code that it has showed me has had a lot of errors and because I am new to php I have a hard time debugging the code.

so I get this warning: Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\simple_blog\inc\functions.inc.php on line 76

here is the function where it is failing

```
function retrieveEntries($db, $page, $url=NULL)
{
/*
 * If an entry URL was supplied, load the associated entry
 */
$fulldisp = NULL;
$e = array();
    if(isset($url))
    {
    $sql = "SELECT id, page, title, entry
            FROM entries
            WHERE url=?
            LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array($url));

    // Save the returned entry array
    $e = $stmt->fetch();

    // Set the fulldisp flag for a single entry
    $fulldisp = 1;
}

/*
 * If no entry ID was supplied, load all entry titles for the page
 */
else
{
    $sql = "SELECT id, page, title, entry, url
            FROM entries
            WHERE page=?
            ORDER BY created DESC";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $e = $stmt->execute(array($page));

    //$e = NULL;  //Declare the variable to avoid errors

    // Loop through returned results and store as an array
    while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {

        if($page=='blog')
        {
            $e = $row;
            $fulldisp = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            $e = $row;
            $fulldisp = 1;
        }
    }
    //var_dump($row);

    /*
     * If no entries were returned, display a default
     * message and set the fulldisp flag to display a
     * single entry
     */

        if(!is_array($e))
        {
             $fulldisp = 1;
             $e = array(
             'title' => 'No Entries Yet',
             'entry' => 'This page does not have an entry yet!'
              );
        }
    }

// Add the $fulldisp flag to the end of the array
//var_dump($e);

array_push($e, $fulldisp); // line 76

return $e;
}
```

I know that based on the message the varriable $e is a boolean that has the value of false because I used var_dump($e) which I then commented out.  But before line 76 there is an if statement: if(!is_array($e)) which checks if $e is not an array which it would not be because $row is a bool(false) and that is assigned to $e. So I assume that because a boolean value is not an array it will enter this statement: if(!is_array($e)) and in the body of that which is just before  the error on line 76 turns $e back to an array

I know this may be really confusing but I really appretiate any help thank you.

Comment: why are you using array_push, instead of `$e[] = $fulldisp`?

Comment: I'd add some debugging to your code, to see which branch of the if statement was being run. You're getting $e as a boolean because one of the SQL queries is failing, I think, but there's no error checking in the code, so you can't see what the error is.

Comment: What is the value of $e if no result is returned from your database query?

Comment: Elaborate on where the error is occurring in the code. The lines aren't numbered for us, and I don't see any where in the code that you're calling `array_push` or checking `is_array`.

Comment: @sh1ftst0rm he is calling array push at the very end to add display flag at the end of the entry array, in order to pass them both using this function

Answer (score 1):

$e is not guaranteed to be an array in your code, there are several code paths that would yield a non-array value of $e.

My guess is on this line

```
  $e = $stmt->fetch();
```

or

```
 $e = $stmt->execute(array($page));
```

is where the non array value is being set.

Test to see if $e is an array prior to using it as one, or structure the code where all code paths result in $e being an array.

Answer (score 0):

`$e = $stmt->execute(array($page));` Is this the issue? Why use `$e` here?

You need to `if($stmt->execute(array($page))){ ... }`.